# Need to convert CategoryID from Items table to CategoryNameA in Categories table inside view model

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, converters, datagridtextcolumn

This is my first question and I apologize for my poor background knowledge. I've managed to fake my wake through a lot of C#/WPF/LINQ-to-SQL but I suspect that while I've gotten a lot of things working, I've done a lot of things the "wrong" way. I've Googled myself in circles over this question. My question seems like it should be simple and obvious.

I have two tables represented in my view model.

`IQueryable<> Items` is the items source for my datagrid. It has a column for `CategoryID`.

Categories are defined in a separate table with `CategoryID` and `CategoryName`.

I'd like to bind my a text column to Item's `CategoryID` and display the corresponding `CategoryName` from the Categories table.

I have accomplished it in what I think is the "wrong" way. It seems like there should be a much more straightforward way. I'd like to know whether my implementation is as silly as I think it is, and if so, what's the right way?

Here's my way:

Instead of using a text column, I'm using a (readonly) `ComboBox` column. I created an `ObservableCollection<Category> Categories` and I populate from the SQL database. I bind the items source of the `ComboBox` column to it and bind the selected value to Items and set the `DisplayMemberPath` to the `CategoryName` column (from `Categories`). It works but it just feels wrong!

Thank you!

Comment: can you add the part of your code that you mention in the last section?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding your CategoryName to your  IQueryable<> Items